# Notify to user when application on a background

Tags: android, timer, background, notifications

I made some application and I'd like to add notification to user when application going on a background after 1hours.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.main);

   }

   @Override
  protected void onPause() {
  TimerTask backgroundCheck = new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
          ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
          List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
          if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
             ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
               if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())) {
                      // APP in background, do something

                }
            }

              // APP in foreground, do something else
   }
 };

 Timer isBackgroundChecker = new Timer();
 isBackgroundChecker.schedule(backgroundCheck, 1000, 1000);

 super.onPause();
}





}
```

This is my code but I don't know how to make it..Please help me with full codes

Comment: Use AlarmManager for this

Answer (score 0):

Better override onWindowFocusChanged. It is only called when the window focus has been changed

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus) {
        startTimer();
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

I would also recommend to use a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) instead of the Timer

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. Please check me it is right or not.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. but I don't know how to apply it. Please help me